# Como definir valores negativos para SeekBar do Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Estou usando Xamarin para desenvolver para Android em C# e verificando a documentação do componente [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) vi que ele só possui uma propriedade "Max", e que o valor mínimo para o componente é 0.

Como seria possível fazer com que o SeekBar aceitasse valores negativos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Até onde sei, não é possível estabelecer um valor negativo. O que eu costumo fazer é aumentar o max para suportar o intervalo e subtrair do valor atual para mostrar o meu intervalo de valores ao usuário.

Digamos que eu tenha um SeekBar de -100 a 100:

```cs
seekbar.setMax(200);
```

e faço a subtração/translação na hora de mostrar ao usuário e/ou salvar o valor:

```cs
int realValue = seekbar.getValue() - 100;
```

Uma manobra similar pode ser feita para valores decimais, por exemplo.

Se você quiser deixar tudo mais elegante, também pode estender a classe SeekBar e criar seu próprio componente que faz esse cálculo internamente, deixando tudo transparente para sua activity:

```cs
public class NegativeSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    protected int minValue = 0;
    protected int maxValue = 0;
    ...

    public void setMin(int min){
        this.minValue = min;
        super.setMax(maxValue - minValue);
    }

    public void setMax(int max){
        this.maximumValue = max;
        super.setMax(maxValue - minValue);
    }
    ...

}
```